# copy only portion of char[] into String

Tags: java, string, char

I have an array char[] ch. My question is the following. How can I merge values from ch[2] to ch[7] into a String? I would like to achieve this without looping through the char array. Any suggestions?

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge values from ch[2] to ch[7]"?  Create a new String?  Insert these characters into a new String?  Overwrite characters in a String?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `new String(value, offset, count)`, [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

Where offset is the starting index and count is your index difference. In your case, it's 7-2=5.

Obviously, value is your character array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the other constructors for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)

There is one that takes a char array, an offset and a length.

```
new String(ch, 2, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        char[] left = new char[]{'l','e','f','t'};
        char[] right = new char[]{'r','i','g','h','t'};
        char[] merge = new char[left.length + right.length]; 
        System.arraycopy(left, 0, merge, 0, left.length);
        System.arraycopy(right, 0, merge, left.length, right.length);
        String mergeString = new String(merge);
        System.out.println(mergeString);
```

Output:

> leftright